# Reset page to initial form

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I load a page in my app, the user does some modifications on it. By the push of a button on that certain page, I want to reset the page to its initial form. I've tried `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));` but it doesn't work, since the From and To pages are the same. Also, I have thought of putting a new page in between, but it sounds bad. Also, it would be best if I didn't have to screw the Navigation History (i.e. the back button) by navigating without reason to another page. So any solution for a page reset? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of changes does the user do? Can you just reset the values (ie remove text from textboxes, reset textblocks to original value, remove images, delete lists, etc... Shouldn't be too difficult. If you have a more complex ui (say with a user moving around Grids / Drawing on screen) you could still do this technique.

Comment: That is the last resort. I would have to write a very large method for rearranging things around.

Comment: I guess you could try deleting the contents of the Layout, and then use XAMLLoader to reload the UI... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/865c6b3d-9548-45fe-a680-9992e63fbbca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right answer. In order to reset the page to its initial form you have to do this:

```
void buttonResetPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     this._contentLoaded = false;
     InitializeComponent();

     // other initializations found in your page constructor
}
```

It worked for me. :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Doesn't feel right but works just fine.

Comment: My answer was posted in 2011. It is very likely that this bug was fixed / changed in the OS builds for the past 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in the following way:

```
ContentFrame.Content = New {pagename}
```

this sets the contentFrame, which contains my webpages page1,page2 etc, to a brand new instance of that page. This then reloads everything on that page, the layout and also gets the data back from the database again. This way worked for me.

Comment: Sounds good, but I don't have the application to test the issue again, so I can not mark you answer. What I can do is upvote. :)

Comment: ContentFrame does not exist as an API, is there something special reference needed in the project?